# dropdown menu IE8 overflow hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, menu, hidden

site in question: http://ecogroovellc.com

When looking at the 2nd child menu drop-down (Portfolio>Music), it appears properly in FF and Safari, but not in IE8, where it is hidden within the 1st child drop-down. Any solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the menu dropdowns? By CSS, or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I tried multiple variations, in the end I added `filter:none !important;` to my css rule on the containing element and that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's because of the `filter` (providing opacity) in IE - it causes an `overflow: hidden`-esque effect.

I attempted to precisely locate it, but there's a *lot* of CSS/JavaScript to look through and I became disheartened.

What you need to do is remove the relevant `filter` rule when the fade transition is complete in your JavaScript.

Comment: unfortunately i'm not certain how to go about removing the filter rule once the transition is complete. thanks so far!

Answer (score 2):

If you set the UL in question (the one with audio and videos) to position:relative, it seems to fix it in ie8, but it screws it up in FF.

Comment: +1, you're right. I'm less certain that my answer is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to compensate for issues on IE8 you should always target it conditionally (add conditional class to HTML then write css targeting .ie8 specifically)

there literally isn't any way to write code that works for everything all at once...